# rego_unsafe_var_error, but only in tests

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I'm writing a test for a rule but am hitting the error below in the test;

```
rego_unsafe_var_error: var canWrite is unsafe
```

The test rule;

```
test_canWrite_allowed {

    canWrite    with data.applications as data_valid    
                with input as input_valid     
                with io.jwt.decode_verify as decoded_token_test  

}
```

Each of the "as" variables/function are defined in the same file as the test

The rule itself is a little long to pull apart to post, but when I put the rule into the rego playground it works.  I can even add the above test into the playground and it works as expected too.

The error only appears when I run "opa test test_myrule.rego" locally.

I know without the full rule nobody can spot the error, but what I'm really after is if someone can tell my why this is happening;

- what does this error really mean - why would my rule be "unsafe"
- any idea why this would work in the playground but not when running through the OPA binary

I'm running version 0.40.0

Answer (score 2):

The rule might be *unsafe* because it's not found in the scope of the test. Do you have the test and rule in different packages? If so, you need to import the rule under test into the test module:

```
package demo

hello {
    input.message == "world"
}
```

,

```
package tst

import data.demo.hello

test_hello {
    hello with input.message as "world"
}
```

It's also possible to split the same package over multiple modules/files by declaring the same package in them, which might be what you actually want to do. Then you don't need the import.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason the variable may be out of scope (if the policy file and test file are part of the same package) is if you are only passing the path to the test file and not the path to the package directory which contains *both* files.

For example, let's say you have the following files:

```
# src/policy.rego
package demo

hello {
    input.message == "world"
}
```

```
# src/policy_test.rego
package demo

test_hello {
    hello with input.message as "world"
}
```

If you try to run the tests with the following command:

```
./opa test src/policy_test.rego
```

You'll still get the following error because the tests don't have access to the variables set in `demo/policy.rego`

```
rego_unsafe_var_error: var hello is unsafe
```

Instead you should pass the path to the package directory:

```
./opa test src/
```